# Tomcat CORS filter

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, cors

I want to enable tomcat CORS filter, i added this to web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

But it doesn't work.
I tried with a custom filter:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SimpleCORSFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.common.SimpleCORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SimpleCORSFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

With this Class:

```
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}
```

And this well works, can you tell me why?
I don't know if it is important but I'm usign Spring Framework.

Comment: How did you test the `CorsFilter`? With AJAX request or with just a simple GET?

Comment: Both, but firebug doesn't show the Access-Control header

Comment: Can you provide a complete example of how to set up SimpleCORSFilter? What are the imports? Where does the class live? I would like to add the class to tomcat and am not sure how.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The filter [**`org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter`**](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter) seek first a header in the request: `Origin`.  If this header does not exist, the filter does not add any header in the response. Perhaps for that reason does not work.

Additionally, in a `POST` request, look for the header `Content-Type`. Something similar happens to other methods. May you want to see the [code](https://github.com/quickhack/tomcat/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/catalina/filters/CorsFilter.java) of this filter. In another way, there is a [flowchart](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/images/cors-flowchart.png):

[image: CORS Flow Chart]

Comment: it doesn't help for me. I added Origin http://www.stackoverflow.com just for the test and tomcat doesn't return the headers

Answer (score 27):

I get a similar problem and I found something that worked for me on tomcat doc [tomcat-doc-CORSFilter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter)
I use filter and **init-param** as below:

```xml
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
    <param-value>10</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to put this to work but it seems that tomcat does not match the `url-pattern` or maybe the Filter is not enable... is there a way to put debug logs ?

Comment: @HarshvardhanSharma You should add/change your code with this one on web.xml file, on path webapp/WEB-INF

Comment: javax.servlet.ServletException: It is not allowed to configure supportsCredentials=[true] when allowedOrigins=[*]

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment but thanks for your answer @Krikza :)

Using Tomcat 9 I had the following issue: `javax.servlet.ServletException: It is not allowed to configure supportsCredentials=[true] when allowedOrigins=[*]`

Simply removing the parameter fixes it

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Answer (score 2):

When I had the same problem, the [tomcat reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/config/filter.html) didn't work. Here's how it worked:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case with Ueditor，the `X-Requested-With` should be `X_Requested_With`.