# AngularJS, Spring Social and CORS

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, cors, spring-social

I have an app that I have built using Spring with Spring Social.

I was able to connect to Social Networks, it worked well. Then I had the great idea to use angular on the front end instead of jsp and set about replacing my html forms that I used to connect to social networks with http posts using angular.

Now I am getting the error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=233119510011-epdnrh651t…%2Fconnect%2Fgoogle&scope=email&state=e29561c9-a538-47dd-8b92-ca0aaa8b413b. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Form posts work, but angularjs posts do not. What gives? I looked at the failing angular post using fidler, compared it to the working html form post and found this.

Working POST using html forms

```
 POST http://localhost:8080/connect/google HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 54
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://localhost:8080/myscene/account-settings
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.679586999.1424266167; JSESSIONID=74A29A5F0B04B937281A7FAC4DD7B102
X-Forwarded-For: 12.13.14.15

_csrf=c71a3881-d272-42de-b8b1-c7647f7e7609&scope=email
```

Here's the code that makes that post

```
<form action='<c:url value="/connect/google" />' method="POST">
                        <input name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                            value="${_csrf.token}" /> <input name="scope"
                            value="email" />
                        <button type="submit" class="common_button">Connect with
                            Google</button>
                    </form>
```

POST that doesn't work using angularjs

```
POST http://localhost:8080/connect/google HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 54
Origin: http://localhost:8080
X-XSRF-TOKEN: c71a3881-d272-42de-b8b1-c7647f7e7609
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Referer: http://localhost:8080/myscene/account-settings
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.679586999.1424266167; JSESSIONID=74A29A5F0B04B937281A7FAC4DD7B102
X-Forwarded-For: 12.13.14.15

_csrf=c71a3881-d272-42de-b8b1-c7647f7e7609&scope=email
```

Here's the code that makes that post

```
$http({
                  method  : 'POST',
                  url     : '/connect/google',
                  data    : $.param(oauth2Scope),  // pass in data as strings
                  headers : { 
                                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                'X-XSRF-TOKEN'   : token,
                                'Cache-Control'  : 'max-age=0',
                                'Accept'         : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
                            }  
                 })
```

Am I on the right track? I've found this quite tricky so any help is more than welcome! Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

**EDIT 1:**

I've created a filter server side but things are not working so there must be something else I need to do.

**EDIT 2:**

Also, it is worth noting the request that generates the error is a GET to google's servers by the Spring Social Framework. My angular POST that causes the issue is to localhost:8080 and is processed by Spring Social.

**EDIT 3:**
So I have noticed this is a problem only when spring social sends that GET to google / facebook and not for my own site. For my own site, I can submit ajax posts using angular fine.

Also, I have noticed the non working GET to google has Origin included where as the working GET to google does not. Could this be the problem?

Filter

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");

        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your servlets/rest services must have the CORS header set and I noticed that `$http` checks the http OPTIONS prior to a call.

The best way to add this features is a filter, that adds the header entries.

See [Tomcat CORS filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386712/tomcat-cors-filter)

Comment: Thank you. I have tried adding a filter via Spring and so have included that in my original question in case there is some problem with it. Beyond that I'm going to study up the flow chart in the link you provided. Looks great.