# how to send a ArrayList with url in jersey?

Tags: java, rest, http, arraylist, jersey

I am using jersey to create a web service . I do have a delete method in REST API, and I need to pass an `ArrayList` from Jersey Client to the REST API. In there , my `ArrayList` type is **DrugNamesBean** .

I have tried in this way but I have no idea about this.

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();          

List<DrugNamesBean> drugNamesBeans=new ArrayList<DrugNamesBean>();
DrugNamesBean bean1=new DrugNamesBean();
bean1.setIdDrugName(23974);

DrugNamesBean bean2=new DrugNamesBean();
bean2.setIdDrugName(23975);

DrugNamesBean bean3=new DrugNamesBean();
bean3.setIdDrugName(23976);

drugNamesBeans.add(bean1);
drugNamesBeans.add(bean2);
drugNamesBeans.add(bean3);  

WebTarget webTarget=client.target("http://localhost:8080/Rest/rest/drug_names")                
            .path("/deleteDrugNames").queryParam("list", drugNamesBeans);

String delete = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).delete(new GenericType<String>(){});

System.out.println("Deleted - " + delete);
```

Below is my REST API method

```
@DELETE
    @Path("/deleteDrugNames")
    public String deleteDrugNames(@QueryParam("list")List<DrugNamesBean> drugNamesBeans){

        DrugNamesInterface drugNamesInterface=new DrugNamesTable();
        String deleteDrugNames = drugNamesInterface.deleteDrugNames(drugNamesBeans);
        return deleteDrugNames;
    }
```

Have you any ideas about this ?

**UPDATE**

I could do above using `jersey post`. Like below,

```
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();          

    List<DrugNamesBean> drugNamesBeans=new ArrayList<DrugNamesBean>();
    DrugNamesBean bean1=new DrugNamesBean();
    bean1.setIdDrugName(23977);

    DrugNamesBean bean2=new DrugNamesBean();
    bean2.setIdDrugName(23978);

    DrugNamesBean bean3=new DrugNamesBean();
    bean3.setIdDrugName(23979);

    drugNamesBeans.add(bean1);
    drugNamesBeans.add(bean2);
    drugNamesBeans.add(bean3);  

    WebTarget webTarget=client.target("http://localhost:8080/Rest/rest/drug_names")                
            .path("/deleteDrugNames");

    webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .post(Entity.entity(drugNamesBeans, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

REST API method,

```
@POST
@Path("/deleteDrugNames")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String deleteDrugNames(List<DrugNamesBean> drugNamesBeans){

    DrugNamesInterface drugNamesInterface=new DrugNamesTable();
    String deleteDrugNames = drugNamesInterface.deleteDrugNames(drugNamesBeans);
    return deleteDrugNames;
}
```

How could I use `jersey delete` instead of `jersey post`?

Comment: REST is not just something that you can make up.  DELETE is a rest verb that is used to `delete` a resource identified by a URI.

Comment: @ScaryWombat: OK....So, you mean I have used wrong keyword? Should I use POST?

Comment: here you go http://www.restapitutorial.com/

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to pass a list that I know of.

```
@MatrixParam("drugId") List<Long> drugIds)

http://localhost:8080/Rest/rest/drugs?drugId=1;drugId=2;drugId=3;
```

and

```
@QueryParam("drugId") List<Long> drugIds

http://localhost:8080/Rest/rest/drugs?drugId=1&drugId=2&drugId=3
```

From Tim Sylvester's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048121/url-matrix-parameters-vs-request-parameters)

> The important difference is that matrix parameters apply to a particular path element while query parameters apply to the request as a whole.

Comment: Post the error you get when changing POST to DELETE.

Answer (score 1):

In general  most of the deletes used to be a deletion of single record with url

http://localhost:8080/Rest/rest/drug_names/{id}

but in your case where multiple record deletes are required then query parameter is the one of the way. when i see your code the bean contains only "durgName"value which is unique value for any drug, so its better to pass the list as comma separated(or any symbol to differentiate the value) list of values in the url.

http://localhost:8080/Rest/rest/drug_names/deleteDrugNames?list=23974,23975

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
@QueryParam("drugId") List<Long> drugIds
```

for

```
DELETE http://localhost:8080/Rest/rest/drugs?drugId=1&drugId=2&drugId=3
```

or single `Id`

```
@PathParam("drugId") Long drugId
```

for

```
DELETE http://localhost:8080/Rest/rest/drugs/{drugId}
```

instead of list of beans for passing as `QueryParam`. It's recommended to remove `deleteDrugNames` from the path because `HTTP DELETE` is used so it is already clear that you're removing - you could make similar method `HTTP GET http://localhost:8080/Rest/rest/drugs?drugId=1&drugId=2&drugId=3` for retrieving drugs information. Also change drug_names to drugs. I would suggest to avoid passing entity body within `HTTP DELETE` request because some servers may not support it unless configured - [Jersey test - Http Delete method with JSON request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36310863/jersey-test-http-delete-method-with-json-request)

Comment: Do you get any exception if you try to change @POST to @DELETE?

Comment: Yes I got one . i don't know how to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

In this example we are going to talk about how you can use @QueryParam annotation to parse URI Query Parameters in a JAX-RS RESTful service.Basically,
@QueryParam denotes that the value of the Query Parameter with the corresponding name will be parsed, and if parsed correctly it will be available on
the method argument denoted with@QueryParam.There are baically two ways to pass parameters in a GET request in REST services. One of them is URI path parameters.
We define this parameter with @Path("/{parameter}") annotation on a method.For example, to pass “Enjoy” as the value of a query parameter called queryparam, 
one should follow URLs with a pattern like this: .../bbb?queryparam=Enjoy.You can use @Context annotation usually to inject contextual Java types related to
the request or response. In a JAX-RS application using servlet, ServletConfig, ServletContext, HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse objects are available
using @Context.

problem:
http://localhost:8080/JAXRS-HelloWorld/rest/helloWorldREST/parameters?parameter2=Examples&parameter2=09709
and you want to collect data from url,so using @Context UriInfo uri object you can directly fetch data in list form.

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>
<code>
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

@Path("/helloWorldREST")
public class HelloWorldREST {

    @GET
    @Path("/parameters")
    public Response responseMsg( @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {

        String parameter1 = uriInfo.getQueryParameters().getFirst("parameter1");

        List<String> parameter2=  uriInfo.getQueryParameters().get("parameter2");

        String output = "Prameter1: " + parameter1 + "\nParameter2: " + parameter2.toString();

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build(); 
    }
}
</code>
</pre>

Use UriInfo  [QueryParam in Jax-rx][1]
```

Comment: Can you also provide a brief explanation of the code?

Comment: problem:
http://localhost:8080/JAXRS-HelloWorld/rest/helloWorldREST/parameters?parameter2=Examples&parameter2=09709
and you want to collect data from url,so using @Context UriInfo uri object you can directly fetch data in list form.