# Enable CORS on Tomcat 8.0.30

Tags: java, cors, tomcat8

Appreciate any help.

I'm facing the problem with the CORS on my newly deployed Tomcat 8.0.30. I keep getting the error below. I am using 127.0.0.1 as the API server address and 192.168.1.100 is the address of my HTTP server.

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '_http://192.168.1.100:8999' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Read through whole Tomcat documentation, added the cors filter under the tomcat web.xml, as well as the project web.xml, but nothing magic happens here, still getting the same error. Tried both minimal and advanced with init-param, same error.

I am using Spring 4 as my rest api framework. Any more configurations need to be done on the project coding part?

Here are the steps I've done so far:

- add cors filter under web.xml, mininal config according to documentation, not working
- add cors filter under web.xml, full config, not working as well.
- tried to use cors filter from http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter.html, still not working

Any suggestions?

[image: network response]

---

Add the web.xml configuration
I've tried to change cors.allowed.origins to *, to 127.0.0.1,192.168.1.100, all not working,
remove credentials and maxage

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>http://192.168.1.100</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

---

Suggested by Vishal, changing tomcat version from 8.0 to 8.5, still same issue

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8080/leyutech-framework-gurunwanfeng/api/ad/getAdInfoByAdType.html?adType=0. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.100:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

Comment: At least provide the configuration you added to the web.xml. I can assure you the Tomcat documentation has it right, I used it myself. But its quite easy to miss-configure it.

Comment: I am unsure whether you are looking for this:     http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter

Comment: Hi Gimby and Azim, yes, I've added from the documentation, both minimal configuration and advanced, both of them are not working

Comment: @ShawnZhou: Am wondering if it might be an issue with the tomcat version you are using. I believe we had something similar in the past, but I cant remember if it was Tomcat or JBoss we were using and that specific version had an issue forcing us to upgrade

Comment: @Vishal Jumani, I've tried the version 8.5.3 as well, but still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used the custom filter to accomplish this issue, I have no idea why offical tomcat cors filter is not working in my case, Any one can suggest the logic behind this, I am willing to try this out.

[Original Post from Tobia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386712/tomcat-cors-filter)

The code is modified from the link above.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

web.xml configuration under current project

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SimpleCORSFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.example.util.SimpleCORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SimpleCORSFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: This is a work around solution for CORS to be working,

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem once and I developed a custom handler for a Jetty Web application.

Maybe it can help you.

**CORSHandler.hava**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

public class CORSHandler extends HandlerWrapper {

    public static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
    public static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS = "Access-Control-Allow-Headers";
    public static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS = "Access-Control-Allow-Methods";

    public CORSHandler() {
        super();
    }

    public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        // Allow Cross-site HTTP requests (CORS)
        response.addHeader(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, "*");

        // Accept Content-Type in header
        response.addHeader(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS, "content-type");

        // Accept GET, POST, PUT and DELETE methods
        response.addHeader(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS, "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE");

        if (_handler!=null && isStarted())
        {
            _handler.handle(target,baseRequest, request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

**Starter.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

import org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper;

import com.example.config.AppConfig;
import com.example.handlers.CORSHandler;

import com.example.properties.*;

public class Starter {

    public static void main( final String[] args ) throws Exception {

        Server server = new Server( 8080 );

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        final ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder( new CXFServlet() );

        HandlerWrapper wrapper = new CORSHandler();
        final ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();

        context.setContextPath( "/" );
        context.addServlet( servletHolder, "/rest/*" );     
        context.addEventListener( new ContextLoaderListener() );

        context.setInitParameter( "contextClass", AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.class.getName() );
        context.setInitParameter( "contextConfigLocation", AppConfig.class.getName() );

        wrapper.setHandler(context);
        server.setHandler(wrapper);

        server.start();
        server.join();  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am also using the custom filter in my case now, I have no idea why the original is not working, I've used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386712/tomcat-cors-filter. Your post is definitely a great guild.