# cross origin requests are blocked in tomcat 8 with HTTP status code 403

Tags: post, cors, tomcat8, http-status-code-403

it may seem like a known issue and many questions exist on the topic, however, my situation is very strange. I have a simple web application that is deployed on tomcat 8.0.36. I have configured the CORS properly:

```
<filter>
<filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The cross-origin requests are blocked by the browser:

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.mytestpage.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

In the tomcat log file I also see the response code of 403. What is interesting is that the code of my application is never executed in case of cross-origin requests. The requests are blocked before reaching my application and 403 is sent immediately. I have no apache in front of tomcat, it's plain tomcat. I have tried many things, including whitelisting the origins and specifying allowed headers - nothing helped. I've also tried to set the header programmatically until I found that the code in case of cross-origin request is never executed.

UPD: The end point accepts POST requests. Those POST requests are sent as XmlHttpRequests from the JS snippet.

Any ideas what it can be?

p.s I can make successful same origin requests.

Comment: Hi,
you use defaults in your `CorsFilter` configuration,
so problem can be with everything.
For example 
`cors.allowed.methods` default value is `GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS` and maybe in request `DELETE` is trying.
Could you post more details?

Comment: I have updated the question. I'm sending POST requests.

Comment: Request is rejected by `org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter`. Try debug it or set you logger to debug level on this class.

Comment: yeap, it's definitely the filter that is blocking the request. How can I debug or put the logger on this specific class?

Comment: What IDE, what logger, what build tool you use?

Comment: the tomcat is deployed on a linux box to which I connect through ssh. I deploy the war file in the {catalina.base}/webapps folder. I have configured the logging and this is what I see:
28-Jul-2016 15:59:57.095 FINE [http-bio-138.188.100.223-8443-exec-12] org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleInvalidCORS Invalid CORS request; Origin="https://"www.mytestpage.com;Method=POST
p.s I had to add quotes,otherwise the protocol wouldn't be shown here

Answer (score 5):

I found what was the issue - I had to set the Content-Type header in the request, otherwise the request would be blocked. - [Tomcat CORS filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386712/tomcat-cors-filter)

Answer (score 1):

You actually have to set both `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`. Here is an example:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.myhost.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
```

Also you have to accept "OPTIONS" method returning both `Access-Control-Allow-*` header lines. Some browsers may issue this kind of request prior to your actual request (e.g. "PUT" request) to get the access information of the service.

Answer (score 0):

I just got into a similar situation. I solved it by using the same Tomcat server for all my needed web apps. Also, I had to use detailed name for the tomcat server instead of localhost. I saw no more CORS filter problems.