# Having issue with CORS filter

Tags: java, spring, cors

I have searched around for whole day on internet. This is what I have included on **web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.sampe.service.context.filter.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Here is the Cors Filter (CorsFilter.java)

```
@Component
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

   @Override
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
      HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
      chain.doFilter(req, res);
   }  

   @Override
   public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

   @Override
   public void destroy() {}
}
```

It works fine on postman. But I am having problem making ajax calls or using angular 2. I have looked around these questions too. [solved stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386712/tomcat-cors-filter) Whats wrong with mine.

Comment: what error you see when using ajax / angular2 calls ?

Comment: This is nothing to do with Angular

Comment: I get "Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)" error in console

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with angular.
The thing is that your spring API does not allow cross origin requests.

To allow your API to be accessible from cross origin you can setup annotations on the rest controller.

What I am trying to say is you can annotate your rest controller with @CrossOrigin , so that it will allow cross origin access.

Hope this helps.
Kudos

Comment: CORS problems are almost always caused by the server. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 1):

You have to annotate your Cors filter with the following annotation :
`@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`
 `@Order` defines the sort order for an annotated component. The default value is `Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE`, indicating lowest priority (losing to any other specified order value).