# Option instead of Post: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check.

Tags: angularjs, rest, http

I am trying to access an rest api source and it is working finde with postman or http requester. What is wrong with my code?

```
let keyUrl ="yourUrl"

getAPIKey(){
   let headers = new Headers();
  //  headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
   headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + btoa(this.cred.user + ":" + this.cred.pw));
   headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT');
   headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","*");

   let options = new RequestOptions({

     headers: headers,
     method: RequestMethod.Post,

    });

    return this.http.post(this.keyUrl,options)
        .map((res: Response) => {
          console.log('##############')
          console.log(res.json())
        })
        .catch(this.handleError)
        .subscribe(
        status => console.log(status),
        error => this.handleError(error),
        () => console.log('DONE')
        );


     }
```

As error I am always getting:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

In my backend the post request is as "Options" even if I sent http.post.

Comment: Your API needs to accept `OPTIONS` requests. (FYI, `application/JSON` requests will always send an OPTIONS requests whereas `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` do not)

Comment: Ok with text plain same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem too and it took me soo long to find the right solution

You will have to set the headers on your server-side, too. They essentially Need to accept "OPTIONS"-requests.

This may depend on your Server that Hosts the REST-API; if you are using an Apache-Server, you can add this to your httpd.conf and it should work:

```
<Directory />
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
             Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "jakartab3:16090, epbtesti:16090, localhost:16090"
             Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
             Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Accept"
             Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Alternatively, it should also work at the Point where you handle the security (if you do). In this case, set the headerys of your HttpServletResponse like

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
```

Hope this fixes your Problem

---

EDIT: trying to explain why you would need to set that:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin prevents other Servers from accessing your REST-Service - and your angular-application runs on it's own server, on port 4200. For the angular-application to be able to Access your REST-service, as I've already said, you need to set the headers in the server that is hosting your REST-Service according to my answer; It can't work elsewhere since this security-feature prevents other servers from accessing your REST-service

Comment: Ok, did it work? If yes, would you mind posting your python-script as a separate answer to your own question and accept it so others can see what helped you?

Comment: With python script it is working. Strange.. How can I do same with Angular2 import requests

url = "path"

r = requests.post(url,  auth=('user', ''))
print(r.text)

Comment: The python script is working because of the same reason that postman and http requester are working; Your angular-application Comes from a different port than your rest-Service I suppose? I just tested your angular-post-request that you posted in the question and it works; so (even though i have not seen an approach for requests like this before) your issue must be that you come from a different port, and postman and the python-script do not

Comment: Your angular-Server runs on port 4200 as your question states;on what port is your rest-Service running? 8080?

Comment: You Need to make the changes I suggested in my answer in the Server that hosts your REST-Service, else it will not accept requests with these methods ('options', 'post') from Servers on other ports - that's the Problem you ran into, and the python-script just doesn't run on an own Server so it uses the Default port which is also likely being used by your REST-service, I think

Comment: because of my last comment - Access-Control-Allow-Origin prevents other Servers from accessing your REST-Service - and your angular-application runs on it's own server, on port 4200. For the angular-application to be able to Access your REST-service, as I've already said, you need to set the headers in the server that is hosting your REST-Service according to my answer; It can't work elsewhere since this security-feature prevents other servers from accessing your REST-service

Comment: Ok I got it. I am using a tomcat and I set the web.xml but not working with <filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

Comment: since I am not too familiar with Tomcat, I searched a bit for that too and came to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386712/tomcat-cors-filter) answer; maybe it helps you?

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. I used nodejs for my case and the request module