# Tomcat enable CORS: POST request from Safari returns 200, Chrome and Firefox return 403

Tags: java, google-chrome, tomcat, cors, catalina

I have backend running on Tomcat 8.5, Java Spring on Amazon EC2 instance.

I make a POST request from my React app. The requests from Chrome and Firefox return 403, while the request from Safari returns 200 and the expected data.

After some research I found out that I must add [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31861187/7245448) code *somewhere* to enable CORS. I am not familiar with Tomcat and don't know where exactly to put this piece of code.

I have the following `web.xml` files listed from running the `find` command:

```
./webapps/host-manager/WEB-INF/web.xml
./webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml
./webapps/docs/appdev/sample/web/WEB-INF/web.xml
./webapps/docs/WEB-INF/web.xml
./webapps/examples/WEB-INF/web.xml
./webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml
./conf/web.xml
```

I tried to add the code in `host-manager/WEB-INF/web.xml` and `host-manager/WEB-INF/web.xml` at the same time and tried to run it, but still get a 403 response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following code to your Spring application. It handles CORS configuration for the entire application.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .headers().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

}
```

Comment: Kushagra, I am a front end developer and need to know exactly where to add this.

Comment: You can add this class anywhere inside your source directory. For e.g. `src/main/java/application/security`. Also remember to add `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security` library to your `build.gradle` or the corresponding library to `pom.xml` if you are using maven.

Answer (score 0):

Even though [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54116247/7487335) tells you how to handle it with Spring, it doesn't answer your original question.

You need to add the [CORS Filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter) to `./conf/web.xml` in your case. From the Tomcat documentation:

> Tomcat provides a number of Filters which may be configured for use
> with all web applications using $CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml or may be
> configured for individual web applications by configuring them in the
> application's WEB-INF/web.xml.